# GroupBy anonymous type doesn't work. In C# it's working

Tags: c#, vb.net, anonymous-types

I'm wondering why `VB.Net` can't `GroupBy` an anonymous type but `C#` can.

I did a bunch of `GroupBys` in my C#-applications and I usually form anonymous types, to ensure the readability of the code.

Now i did it in VB.Net. The ruslt: it doesn't work.

Can somebody explain this behaviour?

C#-Code:

```
public class TestObjekt
{
    public int Ean { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}

public static void Main(params string[] args)
{
    List<TestObjekt> objekts = new List<TestObjekt>()
    {
        new TestObjekt() {Ean = 1, Size = 2, Amount = 10},
        new TestObjekt() {Ean = 1, Size = 2, Amount = 100}
    };

    var query = objekts.GroupBy(
        g => new
        {
            Ean = g.Ean,
            Size = g.Size
        },
        (key, group) => new TestObjekt()
        {
            Ean = key.Ean,
            Size = key.Size,
            Amount = group.Sum(s => s.Amount)
        }).ToList();

    // Wo got one object..
    foreach (var q in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ean: {0}, Size: {1}, Amount: {2}", q.Ean, q.Size, q.Amount);
    }
}
```

VB.Net-Code:

```vb
Public Class TestObjekt
    Public Property Ean() As Int32
    Public Property Size() As Int32
    Public Property Amount() As Int32
End Class

Sub Main()
    Dim objekts As New List(Of TestObjekt)
    objekts.Add(New TestObjekt() With {.Amount = 10, .Ean = 1, .Size = 2})
    objekts.Add(New TestObjekt() With {.Amount = 100, .Ean = 1, .Size = 2})

    Dim query = objekts.GroupBy(
        Function(g) New With
        {
            .Ean = g.Ean,
            .Size = g.Size
        },
        Function(key, group) New TestObjekt() With
        {
            .Ean = key.Ean,
            .Size = key.Size,
            .Amount = group.Sum(Function(s) s.Amount)
        }).ToList()

    'We still got two objects here.

    For Each q As TestObjekt In query
        Console.WriteLine("Ean: {0}, Size: {1}, Amount: {2}", q.Ean, q.Size, q.Amount)
    Next

    query = objekts.GroupBy(
        Function(g) g.Ean.ToString() + "@" + g.Size.ToString(),
        Function(key, group) New TestObjekt() With
                       {
                       .Ean = group.First().Ean,
                       .Size = group.First().Size,
                       .Amount = group.Sum(Function(s) s.Amount)
                       }).ToList()

    'This is working. We Only have one object.

    For Each q As TestObjekt In query
        Console.WriteLine("Ean: {0}, Size: {1}, Amount: {2}", q.Ean, q.Size, q.Amount)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I think the write FOR loop is wrong not the GroupBy().  The GroupBy gives a two dimensional array Group[][].  The first array is the groups and the second array are the items in the group.  You are one writing one item from each Group instead of all items.

Comment: ToList on an Grouping returns the list of values. As you can see in the second for-loop in the vb-code it's working correctly.

Comment: No, it is not working the way you want it to.  You need two for loops nested to get all the results.

Comment: Nope. IEnumerable<T>.GroupBy() returns an IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey,Telement>>. It's a "list" of "key-value-pairs". There is no second dimentsion.

Comment: Yes there is.  Each key in the group can have one or more items.  If you have only one hen why are you using Sum()?

Comment: o_O Before the GroupBy you got multiple entries per key. They are grouped to one item per key. This is why i need the sum. Execute the code and you'll see.

Comment: ..Perhaps you're thinking about the `ToLookUp()`. This is where you got multiple entries per key. But this method only needs one `delegate`, the key-selector. This way you don't have a `Sum`

Answer (score 0):

I am honestly suprised that this has worked in C# rather than being suprised that it doesn't work in VB.NET, to be honest.

The key here is whether and to what degree the compiler-generated classes implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. As I guess, this largely depends on the compiler but also on the .NET framework version you are targeting. If you are targeting a framework version that includes the new struct tuple types, the compiler can use them (that is, I guess, what has happened in the C# application). Otherwise, the compiler has to create the old compiler-generated classes (what has apparently happened in VB.NET). But maybe, the support for tuple types is lacking in the VB.NET compiler, I simply don't know.

What is causing this issue is that the struct tuples implement Equals and GetHashCode in an algebraic sense - two tuples are considered equal if and only if their elements are equal. The old compiler-generated types did not implement Equals or GetHashCode and therefore, two tuples of the same elements are treated as different.

Comment: GetHashCode works different in C# and VB. VB => only key-properties. C# => All fields. Correctly explained in the question shown by S.Akbari and Patrick Hofman